# How can I use "public Component getComponentAfter(Container aContainer,Component aComponent)" of LayoutFocusTraversalPolicy class?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jtextfield

How can I use

```
public Component getComponentAfter(Container aContainer,Component aComponent)
```

of `LayoutFocusTraversalPolicy` class? Is it useful to find the next component in Container?

I want to focus next component on firing of `actionEvent` of `JTextField`. Please guide me is it useful for me.

thanks for being so helpful.

Comment: You could use `KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().focusNextComponent()`

Comment: Thanks, Sir. It is working well. @MadProgrammer